# problem of setting audit rules: Syscall name unknown: stime

Tags: redhat, audit, security, auditd

I am setting audit rules in /etc/audit/audit.rules.

As the requirement : The audit system should be configured to audit all administrative, privileged, and security actions.

So I add one line into /etc/audit/auditd.rules:

```
-a exit,always -S stime -S acct -S reboot -S swapon
```

However, after I restart audit.d by service auditd  restart:

```
There is error comeout:
Stopping auditd:                                           [  OK  ]
Starting auditd:                                           [  OK  ]
Syscall name unknown: stime
There was an error in line 14 of /etc/audit/audit.rules
```

It seems stime can't be recognized. 
Could anybody help me to find out what is wrong with my added rule? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

By chance are you running 64 bit?  You might need to qualify the architecture.

So -a exit,always -F arch=b32 -S stime

Let me know.

Comment: Don't forget you can check if an audit is in a certain architecture by running the ausyscall stime x86_64 OR ausyscall stime i686

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you add this to `/etc/audit/audit.rules` instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, in fact, I add it into /etc/audit/audit.rules. But I didn't say clearly in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same on Alpine (64-bit), had to do:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S stime
```